# Solflare web wallet

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, javascript, react, solflare

GM everyone,

Very specific question here ⁉️

Is there any way to connect to solflare web wallet directly, from a program point of view ?

When I try to connect to solflare wallet, I have a pop-up asking to "choose between web wallet and extension".
I would love to skip that step and go straight to the web wallet connection process (pop-up asking to connect wallet).

I tried to connect directly via the solflare web wallet adapter without success... Maybe I missed something !

Thanks a lot in advance for your answer if there is any.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved with the new Mobile Wallet Adapter :
https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/604

It connects directly to the wallet app without asking to connect either to web wallet or extension. Which does not make any sense from a mobile point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Solana-wallet-adapter takes an array of wallets, if you don't want Solflare extension wallet, you can simply not use it. e.g

```
import {
    getPhantomWallet,
    getSolflareWebWallet,
    getSlopeWallet
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';

const wallets = useMemo(
    () => [getPhantomWallet(), getSolflareWebWallet(), getSlopeWallet()],
    []
);

 <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
    <other components />
</WalletProvider>
```

Comment: I would have love the answer to be as simple as that !!! It nearly made my day ...
Unluckyly, "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets" does not expose such interface as getSolflareWebWallet :-/
Or maybe you use something I don't know about, but I am unable to reproduce your code.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer. I'm glad you took the time.

Comment: Ok, looks like a versioning issue, the example quoted using version "0.11.3" of @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets, the getter exist and it only renders the web wallet. 
You can try once with that version to see in action but downgrading to lower version is not recommended.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! The version I'm using currently is "0.18.9".
I'm trying to solve the problem by rewriting the access to Wallet which is not very clean, but so far, I'm seeing no other solution ...